# How to delete all records from a Kendo paged and filtered grid (in the controller)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'd like to add a button to delete all records referenced in a Kendo paged and filtered grid (all paged records) abiding by any grid filters.

Obviously Telerik MVC extensions abstracts the work it does with `iqueryable` at the controller  by the use of the extension `ToDataSourceResult` and the `[DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request` parameter

So the questions are:

- Is it possible to somehow create a custom controller action and associated front end code to pass the current filtering regime
- Is it then possible in the action to delete all records associated with that filtering

*Ie. I might have a paged grid with 1000 records (10 per page), filtered by productId, it would be nice to be able to create a custom toolbar button called "delete all", to delete all the matched filtered records*.

Please note, the toolbar button I can do, however I'm not sure if Telerik lets you have access to iqueriable and DataSourceRequest mechanism in a way that might make this feasible.

Pointing me in the right direction would be sufficient.

### Update

Since I'm actually dealing with millions of records, a server side solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I don't know if there is better solution but I found this one. I don't pretend that it is perfect.

You can use the idea with custom button and attach click event to it.
In the click event handler you must extract what you need (filters, sortings etc.) from the data source. All the DataSourceRequest class properties can be extracted from JavaScript dataSourceo object:

```
dataSource.sort() dataSource.filter(), dataSource.group(),
dataSource.aggregate(), dataSource.page(), dataSource.pageSize()
```

You must extract them with kendo specific method, format them as form-data (json didn't work in my case, I don't know why :( ), send them to the controller via ajax, in the controller write your server side logic based on DataSourceRequest request.

**Script:**

```
function deleteAllEventHandler(){
   var dataSource = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;

   var dataSourceRequest = dataSource.transport.parameterMap({
        sort: dataSource.sort(),
        filter: dataSource.filter(),
        group: dataSource.group(),
        aggregate: dataSource.aggregate(),
        page: dataSource.page(),
        pageSize: dataSource.pageSize()
   });

   var data = "";

   for (var key in dataSourceRequest) {
       if (dataSourceRequest[key] !== undefined) {
           data += key + "=" + dataSourceRequest[key] + "&";
       }
   }

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF",
        url: "@Html.Action("DeleteAllAction", "MyController")",
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            dataSource.read();
        }
   });
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult DeleteAll([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    // Here you must parse the request to expression tree with custom logic
    // or use the folliwng logic:

    // It's very important to return IQueryable here so you can apply kendo
    // filters without fetching all data from the dataprovider (sql server)
    var items = YourDataProvider.GetQueryableItems();

    // Applying the kendo filters on your queryable.
    // I don't know if there is a better way but I use this one. 
    var result = items.ToDataSourceResult(); 

    // Delete items
    YourDataProivder.DeleteItems(result.Data);

    // return Success 
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
}
```

I still think that client side extracting Ids and sending only them to the server for deletion is a better solution but feel free to use this approach if it fit better in your case or has better performance or etc.. Good luck.

Comment: Wow thanks again, ill try these both out and mark accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I am not very fimiliar with the kendo mvc wrappers but at the end the helpers result into html and javascript. You can write custom javascript logic for such behavior.

If you use server side paging, sorting, filtering on to client side you have only the currenlty visible items. You can access the data items at any time so add some button and attach click event. In the event handler take the data, get the ids and make (ajax) call to some action that require collection of ids and delete items. After the ajax call is completed successful invoke dataSource.read();

Example:

**cshtml:**

```
<button id="btnDelete">Delete all visible</button>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>().Name("GridId"))
// ... other grid settigns

<script>
    $('#btnDelete').on('click', function () {
        // Add some js confirmation here. confirm( ... )

        // Get the grid and data for current page/filter/sort
        // The data will contain only the currently visible items
        var grid = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid');
        var data = grid.dataSource.data();

        var ids = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            ids.push(data[i].Id);
        }

        // Ajax call to Action that gets collection of ids and deletes items
        // On success call grid.dataSoruce.read();
    });
</script>
```

If you don't use server side operations maybe you can access the ids via jQuery selectors.

```
$('#Grid tr[role=row] td[role=gridcell]:first-of-type') // if the id is the first td
```

Hope this helps you :)

**EDIT:**

Ok if you don't use server side operations you can use **grid.dataSource.view()** // Gets the current visible items

Actually if you use server side operations you can use the view() method too instead of data()

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, Unfortunately i'm dealing with millions of records so everything has to be done at the server, however you've inspired me with a work around if need be, however ill leave this open for while just incase

Comment: IMO it's not so bad to iterate over items and select their ids on the client side (even when they are millions). If you want pure server side you must send all currenlty applied filters, sorting, page, pageSize etc. and parse them on the server side (I think that this solution will be harder and worse). If you decide to go in this way you can access everything you need from the dataSource object. I will write another answer cause of stackoverflow's comments limited features.